# More results than expected Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to make a method than returns the second bigger number of an array.
When I return the value, in console appears 2 or more values. I can't understand why is this happening. Can somebody help me to understand this, please?
I did a method to search the bigger value so I can use it on the one which returns the second bigger.

```
public class ThirdMax {

    public static int maxNum (int[] array) { //Returns the bigger value of the array.

        int aux = 0;    //Variable to store the bigger value found and compare it with the rest.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if(array[i] > aux) {    //If the actual value is bigger than the aux
                aux = array[i];     //override the aux value with actual value.
            }
        }
        System.out.println(aux);
        return aux;
    }

    public static int secondMax(int[] array) {  //Returns the second bigger value on the array.
        int valorMax = maxNum(array);   //Store the bigger value on a variable so we can use it later.
        int valorMax2 = 0;              //Variable to store the result.
        int[] auxArray = new int [array.length];                                
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] == valorMax) {  //When we get to the valorMax, we replace it in the array with a 0.
                array[i] = 0;
                } else {
                    auxArray[i] = array[i];
                }

            valorMax2 = maxNum(auxArray); //Search again the bigger value after the previous one is replaced by 0.
            }
        return valorMax2;
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: You're calling `maxNum` twice in `secondMax`, and inside that method you have `System.out.println`...

Comment: Thanks, I realized now the fail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `maxNum(auxArray);` multiple times. Each of them prints a max value.

Hence you received multiple result.

To immediately resolve it, remove the print `System.out.println(aux);`
 in your function.

And make only one print function right before you return

```
System.out.println(valorMax2);
return valorMax2;
```

But your code looks not good. It need multiple improvement.

To find the second biggest number, you only need to loop once like this:

```
public static int secondMax(int[] array) {
   int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // Max value
   int secondMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // Second max value, its our result

   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > max) {
        secondMax = max;
        max = array[i];
      } else if (array[i] > secondMax) {
        secondMax = array[i];
      }
   }
   return secondMax;
}
```

This looks OK, but can't extends to find n-th max number, because our if conditions will be very complex. Then you try to find max number once at a time:

```
// Return max number in array which is lower than ceilValue
// Return Integer.MIN_VALUE if no such value found
public static int maxValueBelow(int[] array, int ceilValue) {
   int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i] < ceilValue && array[i] > max) {
         max = array[i];
       }
   }
   return max;
}

public static int findNthValue(int[] array) {
  int maxValue = maxValueBelow(array, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  int secondMaxValue = maxValueBelow(array, maxValue);
  int thirdMaxValue = maxValueBelow(array, secondMaxValue);
  // You can improve this function by give it's a second parameter `n`, and use for loop to find the `n-th` max value.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. What should I do to improve it?

Comment: Sorry but I don't completely understand your code. I'm new on Java. What's the Integer.MIN_VALUE doing?

Comment: That's the constant represent the lowest Integer value. I post another general solution. Hope you get the idea

Comment: And why do you use the lowest Integer value in a max variable? (In the another general solution). Also, why is a constant needed here?

Comment: We want to find the highest value, so we need to compare if the array value is higher than out current max value. To initiate, we need a value that is lower than all array value, so MIN_VALUE is a safe choice

Comment: Ok, I thik I get it.
Could it be possible to have an example without the MIN_VALUE?

Comment: MIN_VALUE is a constant defined in Integer class, you can freely used it. It's just kind of ***marker*** value,  just like you declare `int aux = 0;`, I declare `int aux = Integer.MIN_VALUE`. We just choose the value which is lower than every array member. You choose 0 because you know all other elements are greater than 0. But other can choose -1, -2... and I choose the MIN_VALUE

Comment: Ok, I understand. And what if I can't use this constant? Sometimes in college they forbid me to use some Java utilities, like this one for example. How could I solve it without MIN_VALUE? Is it possible?

Comment: But beware if you cant found the n-th max, you should return something else to indicate instead of return first valur

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the largest number to 0 you really don't need auxArray.
You also don't need a second valorMax.
You might want to refactor your code to the following.

```
public static int secondMax(int[] array) {  
    int valorMax = maxNum(array);   
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == valorMax) { 
            array[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return maxNum(array); // just return the result of maxNum(array)
}
```

be sure to remove the print statement from maxNum if you don't want your program to print 2 numbers to console.

Comment: I need to clarify some things I'm not sure about:

1.Shouldn't I need a new array (which is the copy of the original array but with the new value = 0) to enter it on the function?

2. Why will not return the same larger number again on the return?

Answer (score -1):

Because you put get second max function in the wrong place.

```
public static int secondMax(int[] array) {  
    int valorMax = maxNum(array);   
    int valorMax2 = 0;             
    int[] auxArray = new int [array.length];                                
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == valorMax) { 
            array[i] = 0;
            } else {
                auxArray[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
    valorMax2 = maxNum(auxArray); // this should be out of loop
    return valorMax2;
    }
```

}